# Fetch list of data under a Querybuilder in TypeORM

Tags: query-builder

I have two tables, Users and Events... using QueryBuilder I can fetch some data using leftjoin and other stuff.. but how can I append a list of related registers from table Events so the result become something like

```
[
{ 
   "name": name
   "events:[{    
   }]
}
]
```

I want a list of related data in JSON format using querybuilder